# Are there any potential solutions that avoid this bad answer getting the bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty, specific-answer

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405606/why-are-my-messages-not-sending-to-the-socket-io-room-with-this-handler) related to Socket.io, added a bounty days later, and through further research, discovered the answer: You can't change socket IDs in Socket.io without breaking the Rooms system entirely.

The answer currently provided is terrible, the guy was trying to be helpful, I guess, but he seems to know far less about Socket.io than I do. I don't want to award the points to such a horrible answer, and I already answered the question myself, but I can't award the points to myself.

Are there any potential solutions that avoid this bad answer getting the bounty?

Comment: If you don't award the bounty manually, and after the bounty grace period no answer will have a score of 2 or more, the bounty will not be awarded to anyone.

Comment: Here's what I've done in the past. http://i.stack.imgur.com/HgJUe.png Tho, the guy who answered yours was doing his best, not trying to get half a bounty through dickery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downvote the bad answer.

Answers with a score below 2 won't automatically be awarded the bounty.

Also see the help [page about bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).